# Combine image and tabular data in pytorch (extending ResNet)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am working now on my master thesis. And I want to extend the ResNet50 model to add tabular data. Has anyone experience in similar task? I use an iterative DataLoader and it may causes problems. In general I would like to ask if it's a good idea to create a network with mixed data types (image + tabular) and if this is the right approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question but I find this blogpost might answer your question very well:

[Markus Rosenfelder's blog](https://rosenfelder.ai/multi-input-neural-network-pytorch/)

In summary, it explains how to combine a CNN (like your ResNet50) and tabular input to one model that has a combined output (using Pytorch and Pytorch Lightning but I feel the tutorial is so well done that you can easily adapt the technique to whatever you are using). The tutorial includes the whole process so your problems regarding the DataLoader might be addressed as well.

Hope this helps!